# What is the meaning of "tiller"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, littérature

The question is on this sentence by Louis-Ferdinand Céline : "que ça vous tinte plein les soucis... vous triche le temps, vous tille la peine, lutine, mutine, tinte aux soucis, et *ptemm! ptemm!*"

Without reading the editor's note, I figured "*tille*" related to the verb "*tiller*". But the editor understands "*tille*" as a shortened version of "tintiller".

I was thinking, does this really make sense? Could "*tiller*" be a shortened form of "tintiller" in this case?

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tiller commence par « Battre, broyer … » déjà que la ‘peine’ est douloureuse, la tiller comme on « tille la tige des plantes textiles » devient un supplice.

Comment: @Personne: Voilà une bonne réponse, n'est-ce pas ?

Answer (score 1):

La note du responsable d'édition s'explique parfaitement (à mon avis). Et s'il a pris le soin de mettre la note c'est pour qu'on ne croit pas que Céline ait voulu dire *tiller*, ce qui ici n'aurait aucun sens.

Céline a modifié le mot pour l'avoir le plus court possible de façon à donner un certain rythme à la phrase (une syllabe en plus ou en moins ça compte). La phrase est construite sur les sons, non seulement à cause des nombreuses allitérations, mais aussi par un vocabulaire pris dans le champ sémantique de l'univers sonore et musical : *trille, tinte, note en notes, arpège*, onomatopées...  *Tintiller* raccourci en *tille* a parfaitement sa place dans ce paragraphe.

Pour ce qui est de l'expression « vous (tin)tille la peine » je pense qu'il faut, comme souvent chez Céline, élargir le sens original des mots. Il est facile de passer de *(tin)tiller* à *faire résonner*, et *faire résonner* c'est aussi *amplifier* etc. On peut laisser filer son imagination. Ce rapprochement de mots, apparemment sans rapport, n'est ni plus ni moins surprenant que  « tinte ... les soucis » ou « triche le temps ».

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, mais j'ai  encore du mal à comprende "(...) vous tille la peine (...)" en supposant que "tille" soit une aphérèse de "tintiller". La note de l'édition est signée par Henri Godard mais cette hypothèse est conçue par A. Juilland.

Comment: @ovide Comprenez-vous mieux  « vous triche le temps » tricher et temps qu'on ne rapproche pas d'habitude ! Vous tintille la peine/ fait résonner votre peine... il faut à mon avis comme souvent chez Céline élargir considérablement le sens de mots.

Comment: Merci ! Si vous me permettez de le dire, j'apprécie beaucoup l'acuité de vos réflexions littéraires.

Comment: J'ai relu les passages où Celine décrit, dans Guignol's Band I, la musique anglaise jouée au piano, et il la décrit comme un "bastringue", "du casse-sentiment", "clinquante"... ce n'est pas le genre de musique qu'aurait "amplifié les peines", il me semble. C'est porquoi le verbe "tiller" m'a paru plausible dans ce cas.

Answer (score -1):

As [Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne) mentioned the word **"tiller"** is an alternative word for **"teiller"** and defined here by [CNTRL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tiller). It translates in english to the verb **"scutch"**.

**"Scutch"** as defined by [Miriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scutch): "to separate the woody fiber from (flax or hemp) by beating"